# Treat node group as 'final image' with vector input

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, procedural

After you have created a node setup ( eg. creating a shape from operations on co-ord constituents ) is there a way to alter the resulting output with a new vector input ?

I could create an image instead, and use the vector input to map the location, rotation, scale etc. However I want to use a custom generated UV co-ordinates on a custom shape without making it an image texture. The reason for this is to retain the procedural elements.

Ideally the solution would be either a custom node script, or a technique whereby a nodegroup can be treated as a texture, with it's own vector input affecting the result , not the input.

Comment: How would this be different from a node group with a vector input?

Comment: A vector input says nothing about how that vector is used inside of the node group. My question is specific to how new mapping coordinates can be used on a node group. (similar to if you exported a nodegroups result as an image, brought it back in as an image, and then applied new mapping vector )
Substance Designer has the transform node which can be used in this way, as well as the pixel processor node.